# Fetching TableView with NSDictionary

Tags: ios, xcode

I think this is simple but I can't make it work..

I have a text field, where I enter a String... Then I send it to a web service.

I get the JSON and parse it.

```
- (void)requestFinished:(ASIHTTPRequest *)request

// some code ::::::


NSLog(@"OkRequest || %@ ", jsonDictionary);

for (NSDictionary *ville in jsonDictionary)
{
    NSString *title = [ville objectForKey:@"label"];
    NSLog(@"%@", title);

}
```

I make the NSDictionary, but when I want to set it into a table View... I don't know how to send that Dictionary to another method.

Comment: `jsonDictionary` is NSArray object or NSDictionary object?

Comment: It is a NSMutableDictionary:     
    NSMutableDictionary *jsonDictionary = [parser objectWithString:theJSON error:nil];

Comment: Yes it works... it returns this.
From this : NSLog(@"%@", title);

2012-04-19 12:33:30.137  [15180:11603] Nancy, Lorraine
2012-04-19 12:33:30.138  [15180:11603] Nantes, Pays de la Loire

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Declare a class member `NSDictionary *_jsonDict;`

In `requestFinished:` method, assign the value to the class member and retain that. Then reload the table view as `[self.tableView reloadData];`

In your `cellForRowAtIndexPath:` method, get the value from the dictionary and set it to the label.

Update:

```
- (void)requestFinished:(ASIHTTPRequest *)request
{
      ... some code
     _jsonDict = [jsonDictionary retain];
     [self.tableView reloadData];
}
```

Comment: I did not get the thing when you say assign the value and retain it... Neither for the reload table. I think it is inside another method?

Comment: I think I just need help with the value to the class... I don't get that pretty much...

Comment: Thanks... So, as I can see... TableView needs the JSON like this: [{id:bla; lol:yeah;}] and not like a normal text?

Comment: I now have this.... - (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    return [_jsonDict count];
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return 1;
}

Comment: - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
    
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
        cell.textLabel.text = [_jsonDict objectForKey:@"label"]; // set the cell's text here
    }
    return cell;
}   But I think something is missing

Comment: Please edit your question with your latest code and mention your doubt. You are saying something is missing. If you mention what is missing, then only we could come with some solution.

Comment: Thanks I finally got it. It was a variable problem. THanks